# How debug 401 unauthorized error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I want to post json to the server, I created json and passing it. But getting The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized error. Can some one help me with that.

I have posted my code:----------------------------------------------------------

```
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://synapsepay.com/api/v2/user/create");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"email\":\"nikunj@synapsepay.com\"," +
                      "\"fullname\":\"nik\"," +
                      "\"phonenumber\":\"111\"," +
                      "\"ip_address\":\"1.1.1.1.1\"," +
                      "\"password\":\"123123123\"," +
                      "\"client_id\":\"116db45feb835d2cd5d2\"," +
                      "\"client_secret\":\"ba1c5db06d50d047ac294f4acb31cf0958bcfdf6\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I have posted required fields below:--------------------------------------------

Request Headers requires:-

```
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 280
```

Request Data:-
only email, full name, phonenumber and ip_address, client id and client secrate is mandatory 
This is accepted input, from their website.

```
{
    "email": "nikunj625@gmail.com",
    "fullname": "nikunj mange",
    "phonenumber": "4089170880",
    "ip_address": "1.1.1.1.1",
    "dp": "a",
    "password": "123123",
    "client_id": "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@",
    "client_secret": "#######################################"
}
```

I dont know what i am doning wrong..

and this is the API I am using.

```
http://api.synapsepay.com/v2.0/docs/create-a-usercustomer
```

Comment: Unauthorized error indicates the login credentials do not have permission. Do you have another set of credentials to use?

Comment: @kanchirk its valid, i got it from by mail.. Let me change it or request new and try it. You can visit that link...for more info. I was trying to solve this thing from past 3 hrs but it giving me same error.. please help

Comment: @Nasreddine its not a problem, that is accepted input..

Comment: Did you authenticate?  http://api.synapsepay.com/v2.0/blog/best-authentication-practices-with-synapsepay

Comment: @user3788832 Nikunj,... Try to use another username/password and try. Maybe a different client_id and client_secret.. Btw it is not a good PRACTICE to post these details on internet anywhere. Delete them asap. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Comment: yaa, they have field where i can insert my client id and client secrate id, they are fine..@Nix ...

Comment: Did you try that exact payload on their "test api"

Comment: @kanchirk its for test purposes, they have two apis.. One for test purpose and other for real world.. bu thanks

Comment: Its a real api and I foobared your keys because they are the real ones.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Nix Any suggestions ???? I removed key, requested new keys.. Still same error...

Comment: I ran a test and received this error:
{
    "reason": "Email already registered.",
    "success": false
}

Comment: @JimmyV i changed email id, to create new user i need client id and client  secrete... i can change Email ids.. and that give me auth_key... as response

Comment: I changed the email to nikunj625q@gmail.com and it registered using the previous dev credentials. I think the environment keys might be getting mixed up.

Comment: @JimmyV Yaa.. Its working.. I was using wrong API url.. It supoosed to be sanbox.. Sorry my bad .. Thanks for help

Comment: All good man, we've all been there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an email already exists error.

You need to check the response and look at the "success flag & reason.

[image]

Comment: client id and client secrete i requires for creating new user... i changed email address.. still same error.

Comment: I was able to create a user no problem.  try test+111111111@gmail.com